# How to update some database records with values from form elements in a table

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

I use the code snippet below to generate some form inputs.

```
<tr id='$ticket->id' class='ticket-row'>
    <td>$ticket->ticket_no</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='c_name[]' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='next_of_kin[]' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='address[]' value='$ticket->address' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='seat_no[]' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='fare[]' value='$ticket->fare' /></td>
</tr>
```

Some form elements contain input values from a database. Each `tr` tag contains the record `id` for that row.
My challenge is how best to retrieve the form values in a row alongside with the record's `id` and update the individual records (probably using a loop) after editing the values.

I tried using `ajax`, but I got stuck somewhere. Below is part of the snippet I tried:

```
var tickets = $('.ticket-row');
    $.each(tickets, function(i, val) {
        // Retrieve the form elements in this row and send to the server
    });
});
```

Comment: Ajax is definitely a good approach, could you post the rest of your AJAX code?

Comment: @abase The ajax part is not really my challenge, but how to retrieve the individual input elements. Smoky's answer below looks like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the full table :

**EDIT:** Add [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to your page

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr id='$ticket->id' class='ticket-row'>
        <td><span id="no">$ticket->ticket_no</span></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='c_name' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='next_of_kin' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='address' value='$ticket->address' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='seat_no' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='fare' value='$ticket->fare' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var tickets = [];

$('.ticket-row').each(function() {
    tickets.push({ id : $(this).attr('id'),
                  no : $(this).find('#no').text(),
                  c_name : $(this).find('#c_name').val(),
                  next_of_kin: $(this).find('#next_of_kin').val(),
                  address : $(this).find('#address').val(),
                  seat_no : $(this).find('#seat_no').val(),
                  fare : $(this).find('#fare').val() });
});

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '**URL_HERE**',
    data : JSON.stringify(tickets),
    dataType : 'json'
})
.success(function() {
    // TODO
})
.fail(function() {
    // TODO
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using Json data type, shouldn't the array index and values be in a quote?

Comment: I'm having issues using the return data on the server side using php. First, I tried to convert it to an associative array using json_decode, but trying to access each associative index gives me the error "undefinded index". Please how do I access the return data on the server side? I use PHP. Thanks.